# TFS - How to create a build definition for branch

Tags: tfsbuild, branching-and-merging

Currently, we have a TFS setup with no-branch. But soon after we go live we like to adopt a branch per Release model.

I'm ok with branching side, what I'm not sure is whether we need to create a separate Build Definition for branch.

Below is how Build has been set up:

> 1. UAT_Build. (Builds and deploys to UAT Server)
> 2. QAT_Build  (Builds and deploys to QAT Server)
> 3. PRD_Build. (Builds and deploys to PRD Server)

Could someone please help me understand whether we need to create a separate Build Definition for every Release (1..N)?

e.g.

> 1. Release1_UAT_Build. (Builds and deploys to R1 UAT Server)
> 2. Release1_QAT_Build  (Builds and deploys to R1 QAT Server)
> 3. Release1_PRD_Build. (Builds and deploys to R1 PRD Server)  .....

Note, for each Release the destination web server could be different.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a build definition per branch.

Comment: hmm... is this a best practice. Lets say we have 50 releases, there will be 50x3 build definitions.

Comment: But you should have only 1 branch for Release - which holds the current stable version you deployed on LIVE. If you wanted to revert to some older version you could always do that in the Release branch and rebuild.

Comment: i'm quiet new to TFS build. I thought we should have separate branch for each release? e.g. Release 1, Release 2.... So that we can always refer to the code for each release.

Comment: @Myagdi you don't have to keep the build definitions after the release has dropped out of circulation, just archive off the drop folder and delete the build + definitions.